# RAW format with RenderScript

Tags: android, renderscript

I am trying to preview RAW frames and histogram the values in an efficient way.  In YUV format, this can be done by setting a RenderScript Allocation as a target surface in the Camera2 API:

```
Allocation ain = Allocation.createTyped(mRS, new Type.Builder(mRS, Element.YUV(mRS))
            .setX(mPreviewSize.getWidth())
            .setY(mPreviewSize.getHeight())
            .setYuvFormat(ImageFormat.YUV_420_888)
            .create(), Allocation.USAGE_IO_INPUT | Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);

Surface surface = ain.getSurface()
mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface), mStateCallback, null);
```

and then using `ScriptIntrinsicHistogram`.  Is it possible to stream RAW images directly to an `Allocation` as well?

I know that `ScriptIntrinsicHistogram` only works for type `uchar` and RAW typically has 10 bits.  However, I am more interested in the 0-255 range anyway, so I would be satisfied with truncating the leading bits first in a RenderScript kernel.

I also know that the RAW buffers can be acquired with an `ImageReader`, copied to an array, and then re-copied into an `Allocation`, but for 16 MP images I would hope that a more efficient solution would be possible.

Thanks